# Como inverter um array de caracteres em C?

Tags: c, array, helper

tenho que inverter um vetor, exemplo: ola = alo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
int main()
{
    char c[5];
    scanf("%s" ,c);
    for(int i=5; i>=-1;i--)
    printf("%s" ,c[i]); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você percorrer a *string* inteira e exibiu ela mesma `print("%s", c)` a cada iteração. Não deveria exibir um caractere por vez?

Comment: print("%s", c[i]) tbm n funciona

Comment: Porque `%s` espera uma cadeia de caracteres e você está passando apenas um. Tente ler e entender o que cada parte do código que está escrevendo faz.

Comment: printf("%c" ,c[i]); usei o %c ele volta o resultado correto mas antes uma "?"

Comment: retorno:12345
54321

Comment: mas volta com um caracter especial parecido com uma itnerrogaçao

Comment: `for(int i=strlen(c);i;)putchar(c[--i]);`

Comment: Lembre-se de que em uma string em C você precisa prever o espaço para o terminador '\0'. Se você quer armazenar 5 caracteres declare char c[6]; (índices de 0 até 5). Para imprimir ao contrário: for (i=5; i>=0; i--) printf("%c", c[i]);

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer inverter o array e não apenas escrever seus valores invertidos você deve criar outra variável. Uma maneira de fazer é assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char c[10];
    char invertida[10];

    scanf("%s", c);
    // strlen() retorna o tamanho da string
    // for soma o j e percorre c invertido
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=strlen(c)-1; i>=0;i--) {
        invertida[j] = c[i];
        j += 1;
    }
    // Finaliza String
    invertida[j] = '\0';

    printf("%s", invertida); 
    return 0;
}
```